# AJAX getting posts from wpquery, prevent post duplication

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to AJAX loading posts in my blog, I've successfully get it to work this way:

the page displays 3 posts on page load, then the visitor can get 3 more posts each time he clicks the button "LOAD MORE".

Now I want to load 9 posts on page load but keep 3 posts with each click on "LOAD MORE" button.

A problem occurs with the page number value in the WPQuery, it's getting the same 3 posts which were already displayed.

how can I prevent posts duplication?

Please check it here at  [my temp website](http://murhafsousli.com/category/uncategorized/)

*[note that I have less than 9 posts at the category page, it should load all of them]*

```
(function($) {
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $content = $('#list-content');
    var $btnLoad = $('#btnLoad');
    var loading = true;
    var page = 1;
    var load_posts = function($count){
        var post_id = $(this).attr( 'id' );
        /** Ajax Call */
        $.ajax({
            cache       :   false,
            timeout     :   8000,
            url         :   php_array.admin_ajax,
            type        :   "POST",
            data        :   {action:'main_query', numPosts : $count, pageNumber: page, condition: php_array.condition, val: php_array.val},

            beforeSend  :   function() {
                $('#loadimg').slideToggle("fast");
                $btnLoad.prop("disabled",true);
            },
            success     : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR ){
                var $data = $( data );
                if($data.length){
                    $content.append( $data );
                    $btnLoad.prop("disabled",false);
                }
                else{
                    $btnLoad.html("That's it");
                    $btnLoad.prop("disabled",true);
                }
            },
            error       : function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
                if(t==="timeout") {
                    alert("Server is too slow, try again later");
                } else {
                    alert(t);
                }
                console.log( 'ajaxLoop.js: The following error occured: ' + textStatus, errorThrown );  
            },
            complete    : function( jqXHR, textStatus ){
                $('#loadimg').slideToggle("fast");
                loading = false;
                page++;
            }
        });
    }
    $btnLoad.on("click", function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        loading = true;
        load_posts(3);
    });
    load_posts(9);  //load the first elements
});

})(jQuery);
```

PHP code:

```
function main_query_init() {
/** Made Query */
$numPosts = (isset($_POST['numPosts'])) ? $_POST['numPosts'] : 0;
$page = (isset($_POST['pageNumber'])) ? $_POST['pageNumber'] : 0;
$condition = (isset($_POST['condition'])) ? $_POST['condition'] : '';
$val = (isset($_POST['val'])) ? $_POST['val'] : '';
$args = array(
        'posts_per_page'=>  $numPosts,
        'paged'         =>  $page,
    );
if($condition != ''){
    $args[$condition] = $val;
}
$post_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ($post_query->have_posts()) : while ($post_query->have_posts()) : $post_query->the_post();
```

Comment: there are errors in your php code segment

Comment: @SamuelCook where exactly, can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is `var currCount = $data.filter('article').length;`
where I store the current count of posts from ajax response.

Since I ask for extra 3 posts every load button click, then `if((currCount % 3) == 0)` will tell me if it got 3 posts otherwise there are no more posts and there is no need to increment `page` counter.

```
success     : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR ){
    var $data = $( data );
    var currCount = $data.filter('article').length;
    totalCount += currCount;
    if(currCount > 0){
        $content.append( $data );
        $btnLoad.prop("disabled",false);

        if((currCount % 3) == 0)
            page += currCount / 3;
        else 
            page += (parseInt(totalCount/3) + 1);
        return;
    }
    $btnLoad.html("That's it");
    $btnLoad.prop("disabled",true);
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for the [`offset` parameter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters) for `WP_Query`. Setting it to `3` will cause it to skip the first 3 results when using `posts_per_page` and `paged`.

The other option is to specify the `post_id`s that you don't want explicitly using the [`post__not_in` parameter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters), but this will require passing the array of values to exclude with each request - you might be able to get away with just passing in the first 3 IDs, but I would go with `offset`.